# Keras - ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a network with multiple inputs with different shapes.
Inputs = [state, other_inputs]

state -> (40, 40, 1)
other_inputs -> (3)

Although I am not having problem while predicting, there is something problematic when it is trained on batches.

**Model :**

```
 def create_model(self, input_shape=(40, 40, 1)):
        input_map = Layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
        input_other = Layers.Input(shape=(3))


        x = Layers.Conv2D(64, 5, strides=1, padding="same",
                          activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1), use_bias=True, bias_initializer='zeros')(
            input_map)
        x = Layers.Conv2D(64, 5, strides=1, padding="same", use_bias=True,
                          activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1),
                          bias_initializer='zeros')(x)

        x = Layers.Conv2D(1, 5, strides=1, padding="same", use_bias=True,
                          bias_initializer='zeros')(x)
        x = Layers.Flatten()(x)
        x = Layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))(x)
        x = Layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))(x)

        x = Layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))(x)

        concatted = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x, input_other])
        output = Layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(concatted)


        model = Model(inputs=[input_map, input_other], outputs=output)
        model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),  # , decay=0.000001),
                      # optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0001),
                      metrics=["mae"])
        model.summary()
    return model

enter code here
```

**Training :**

```
 def train(self, memory, target_model, batch_size, learning_rate, discount_factor, episode,  rarl_wins):
        X_train = []
        y_train = []
        y_pred = []
        self.gamma = discount_factor
        mini_batch = random.sample(memory, batch_size)

        states = np.array([transition[0] for transition in mini_batch])
        other_inputs = np.array([transition[1][0] for transition in mini_batch])
        qs_list = self.model.predict([states, other_inputs], verbose=0)

        next_states = np.array([transition[4] for transition in mini_batch])
        next_other_inputs = np.array([transition[5][0] for transition in mini_batch])
        next_qs_list = target_model.predict([next_states, next_other_inputs], verbose=0)

        for index, (state, other_inputs, action, reward, next_state, next_other_inputs, complete, expert_qs) in enumerate(mini_batch):
            if not complete:
                target = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(next_qs_list[index])
            else:
                target = reward

            qs = qs_list[index]
            qs[action] = (1 - learning_rate) * qs[action] + learning_rate * target

            X_train.append(np.array([state, other_inputs[0]]))
            y_train.append(qs)

        X_train = np.array(X_train)
        y_train = np.array(y_train)
        # print(X_train)
        # input()

        # X_train = tf.cast(X_train, dtype=tf.float32)
        # y_train = tf.cast(y_train, dtype=tf.float32)

        history= self.model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=int(batch_size/5),shuffle=True)

        return self.model, history
```

Finally it gives the error following.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\sas\train.py", line 397, in <module>
    main()
  File "\sas\train.py", line 236, in main
    _, history = agent.train(replay_memory, target_model=target_agent.model,
  File "\sas\ddqn\PAgent.py", line 226, in train
    history= self.model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=int(batch_size/5),shuffle=True)
  File "\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You need to specify in which line it fails.

Comment: The stacktrace I provided specifies the line, X_train is the one that causes the error

Comment: Please try again by changing the X_train value into an array and 'float32' type using `X_train = np.array(X_train).astype('float32')`.